# Insulating behind tar paper?

Tags: drywall, insulation, exterior, mold, moisture

I have a home built in 1959 in Southern California with stucco exterior. I’m removing the drywall to do a major renovation and bring my wiring up to code. I noticed there is no insulation and just black tar paper behind the drywall. I spent hours researching and it’s a mix between “don’t do it” and “do it”.

Can anyone chime in and offer me the best practice?

Comment: Asphalt paper?  You mean tar paper?  Asphalt is tar and rocks.  Assorted papers were used before plastic vapor barriers existed.  Sounds like you should look at the more recent building code guidelines for your area (cities often provide a homeowners guide with all the code excerpts relevant to work the homeowner is allowed to do themselves.  If you use heat or AC for any significant portion of the year, insulation will likely pay for itself, and may be required to bring it up to code.  Any time you open a wall in a building, it's a good idea to look at what else can be done while open.

Comment: I corrected it in my message but not my subject I missed it

Comment: Read your question as if it was someone else asking you and you had no idea what they were talking about.  You need to elaborate on what the mysterious "it" is that you are considering doing or not doing, and adding pictures is not a bad idea.  Rather than looking at whether you need to do some specific thing or not, try researching what is regarded as the modern standard for "best" in your area, which will provide you with a full list of things you should do.  Typically the non-electrical inspectors will have a set of specific minimums that you will have to follow before you can close up.

Answer (score 0):

We used 15 lb felt on the walls back prior to tyvek and 30 on the roof. For a backer to the stucco we used tar paper a heavy brown paper with asphalt/tar. I would not disturbed the tar paper it also helps to keep moisture from getting into your insulation so I would leave tar paper intact.